# How to import CSV data to table through Docker container clickhouse-client

Tags: docker, export-to-csv, clickhouse

I'm using Docker for Windows:

- Docker version 18.03.1-ce-win64
- Docker Engine 18.03.1-ce
- ClickHouse client version 1.1.54380
- ClickHouse server version 1.1.54380

For exporting data from table into CSV format I am using the command:

1. Now run `clickhouse-client` container for export

   ```
   $ docker run -it --rm --link clickhouse-server:clickhouse-client yandex/clickhouse-client -m --query="select * from default.table1 FORMAT CSV" > C:/Users/sony/Desktop/table1_data.csv --host clickhouse-server
   ```

   **NOTE**: The above command works perfectly.
2. Now run `clickhouse-client` container for import

   ```
   $ docker run -it --rm --link clickhouse-server:clickhouse-client yandex/clickhouse-client -m -c "cat C:/Users/sony/Desktop/table1_data.csv | clickhouse-client --host clickhouse-server --query='INSERT INTO default.table1 FORMAT CSV' "
   ```

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong when importing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use HTTP-interface of CH to upload data using *curl* - look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/52011930/303298

Answer (score 4):

I think you should mount the `csv` file inside the container first. To mount the file you should add `-v C:/Users/sony/Desktop/table1_data.csv :~/table1_data.csv` option on your docker command. So your docker run command should be like this:

```
$ docker run -it --rm --link clickhouse-server:clickhouse-client yandex/clickhouse-client -m -v C:/Users/sony/Desktop/table1_data.csv:~/table1_data.csv -c "cat ~/table1_data.csv | clickhouse-client --host clickhouse-server --query='INSERT INTO default.table1 FORMAT CSV'"
```

**Edit**

My bad. Mounting inside the file wont work. Try this instead:

```
cat path_to_file/table1_data.csv | docker run -i --rm --link clickhouse-server:clickhouse-client yandex/clickhouse-client -m --host clickhouse-server --query="INSERT INTO default.table1 FORMAT CSV"
```

Already tried on linux, and it works. Since `cat` not works on Windows, I found `type` has same functionality, honestly haven't try it:

```
`type C:/Users/sony/Desktop/table1_data.csv | docker run -i --rm --link clickhouse-server:clickhouse-client yandex/clickhouse-client -m --host clickhouse-server --query="INSERT INTO default.table1 FORMAT CSV"`
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but It is giving error i.e " Bad arguments: unrecognised option '-v' "

Comment: I updated my answer, hope it works on your environment.

Comment: can't run: "the input device is not a TTY.  If you are using mintty, try prefixing the command with 'winpty'"