# How to insert data to Clickhouse from file by HTTP-interface?

Tags: docker, clickhouse

I want to insert data to ClickHouse per HTTP-interface from file. CSV, JSON, TabSeparated, it's doesn't matters.

Or insert data to Docker-container uses **yandex/clickhouse-server**.

Using HTTP-interface, for example:

```
cat source.csv | curl 'http://localhost:8123/?query=INSERT INTO table FORMAT CSV'
```

Using Docker-container, for example:

```
docker run -it --rm --link some-clickhouse-server:clickhouse-server yandex/clickhouse-client --host clickhouse-server {THERE SOME OPTIONS ABOUT INSERT FROM FILE}
```

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you understand the HTTP request format pretty well.  What specific issues are you running into?  Do you have some partial code you can share?

Comment: @DavidMaze no ( I want just put data from files to clickhouse table.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a tutorial in your language of choice to make an HTTP POST request, or maybe a better API for your database system.  Asking questions of SO isn't necessarily the best way to do this: better questions tend to already have almost-working code.  There's some suggestions on [ask] in the SO Help Center.

Answer (score 5):

`curl 'http://localhost:8123/?query=INSERT+INTO+TABLE(field)+VALUES(data)%3b'`

or

`curl -d 'INSERT INTO T FORMAT JSONEachRow {"dataTime":"2020-12-19 03:00:00","transmit_bytes_max":123};' 'http://9.118.102.189:9200/?database=default'`

or

`curl 'http://localhost:8123/?query=INSERT%20INTO%20TABLE%20FORMAT%20CSV' --data-binary @source.csv`

Answer (score 3):

`cat source.csv | curl 'http://localhost:8123/?query=INSERT%20INTO%20table%20FORMAT%20CSV' --data-binary @-`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: `--data-binary @-` argument makes it execute HTTP POST query with contents of stdin while by default it's just GET

Answer (score 0):

For Ruby, you can use Faraday http client:

1. initialize http client:

```rb
clickhouse_settings = OpenStruct.new(
  database: 'clickhouse',
  username: 'clickhouse',
  password: 'clickhouse',
  url: 'http://localhost:8123'
)

client = Faraday.new(url: clickhouse_settings.url) do |connection|
  connection.request :multipart
  connection.request :url_encoded
  connection.request :basic_auth, clickhouse_settings.username, clickhouse_settings.password
  connection.adapter :net_http
end
```

2. Create body for post request with attached csv file:

```rb
payload = { msisdns: Faraday::UploadIO.new('./tmp/msisdns.csv', 'text/csv') }
```

3. Define query. In this example, `msisdns` - is csv file content, which be readed in clickhouse query as table, named msisdns.

```rb
query = <<~SQL
  SELECT *
  FROM deliver
  WHERE abonent_addr IN (
    SELECT * FROM msisdns
  )
  LIMIT 10
SQL
```

4. Make request. in url you could add params: `database` - ch database name, `msisdns_structure`: definition of csv file structure, in this example you can see the string column 'msisdn'.

```rb
response = client.send(:post, "/?database=#{clickhouse_settings.database}&query=#{query}&msisdns_structure=msisdn String", payload)
```